# Infopath 2013 and a list in another site collection

Tags: 2013, infopath, external-content-type

I have a host-based site collection A which has a custom list A and a site collection B with a list B where I would like to have a lookup field to the list A.

Usually, I think you can try this with an external content type, so an external list, and happy days.

Unfortunately, in the list B, the web forms (Display, Edit and New) are customized using InfoPath because the client needed some special behaviour like cascading dropdowns and special validation rules with regular expressions.

So because of that, and because Infopath 2013 cannot display lookup fields to external lists, I am stuck without knowing how can I achieve this.

i saw solutions using the Search for displaying data from a site collection A in a site collection B, but this works well (as I understand) to display data, but I do not think I can use it as a lookup field in my custom list B, right?

Anyone out there that could help me?

Thanks and regards,